# How to set re.IGNORECASE flag in `regex` in pydantic model

Tags: python, pydantic

I want to set the regular expression as case insensitive in a field of a pydantic model

```
class SimpleModel(BaseModel):
    string_with_regex: Optional[constr(strict=True, regex=(r'[a-z]', flags=re.IGNORECASE))] = None
```

Tried the above but it failed to compile. Removed `, flags=re.IGNORECASE)` and the code compiles.

Does anyone know if regex in pydantic support flags?

Thanks.

Comment: Your argument to `regex` has incorrect syntax as I'm sure you were told in the error. If anything, you could try to provide a `Pattern` object to `regex` like so: `regex=re.compile(r'[a-z]', flags=re.IGNORECASE)` But interestingly, this causes a `TypeError`, even though, looking at the Pydantic source code, it shouldn't. This is a curious problem. I'll try and make sense of this. So far I can only say that it seems to be impossible to provide `Pattern` objects here, only strings- And there is no additional parameter for Regex flags in `constr`.

Comment: A workaround is to use validators for the time being: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/